# How to install openni_camera & openni_launch package in ROS groovy on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ros-groovy, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I am using ROS groovy in Raspberry Pi2 with bare bones installation.
i want to obtain the rgb and depth stream from kinect using rosrun commands like
rosrun openni_camera openni _node & rosrun image_view image_view image:=rgb/image_raw

For that,i need to install openni_camera & openni_launch packages in ROS GROOVY.
i have tried that with the procedure of apt-get install but unable to do so.
Is it possible to install these packages in Pi with ROS. If anyone has done that, pls share the steps to do that.

Thanks & Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214542/how-to-install-openni_camera-&-openni_launch-package-in-ros-groovy-on-raspberry-pi/) by [dhiraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/23345/dhiraj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's likely that the binary of the packages you mentioned are not built for Groovy. You can build them from source; for example `openni_camera` clone its source repository in your catkin workspace, and build:

```
cd %YOUR_CATKINWS%/src
git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera.git && cd %YOUR_CATKINWS%
catkin_make
```

But better answer would be to use [ROSberryPi for Indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi) where better support can be expected for longer term, unless you have a reason to stick to 2 generations older distro.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0